# Verify that all values for a kubernetes helm chart have been used

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'd like to check that my kubernetes helm chart does not define unused values in `values.yaml`. This should include any subcharts such that if you've defined `subchart.foo.bar: ???` in the top-level `values.yaml` that key is definitely used in the subchart, or possibly as a short-cut mentioned in the `subchart/values.yaml`.

This is needed to prevent us from shipping bogus "documentation" in the `values.yaml`, for example if a key in a subchart has been changed or removed.

Ideally there would also be some possibility to report on which subchart values have not been overridden in the top-level chart, though this is less concerning.

Are there any existing tools that can help with this?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there isn't a tool for that. However, it shouldn't be that hard to make one, even using bash. For example, you need to export all key/value pairs like this `test.test1.test2` and grep for that string recursively in the templates folder. If you want to read yaml using bash, you can install `shyaml`. If you know how to code in Python, even better.

Comment: It's not enough to grep for the whole path of a variable, you need to understand the templating language to know if it is being referred to (e.g. by changing context) or that indeed  you are looking at a genuine reference and not something that looks like one.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Helm v3 release you can now define a schema for your **values**. On commands like `helm install` your provided values are automatically validated against the schema.

Please see the official documentation: https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#schema-files

Schema validation works for subcharts too, this is also mentioned in the documentation on the link above.

Comment: You can set `"additionalProperties": false` in values.schema.json and get errors when some unknown / unexpected / extra fields are provided as input.
See [this comment](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6422#issuecomment-753620199)

Answer (score -2):

helm lint --detect-unused-values

Comment: I don't believe this flag ever got past proposal stage. It isn't in the latest version of helm at time of writing (3.10.1).

Comment: Only a [proposal](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/7285) as far as I can tell